# Is it possible to balance websocket traffic from a client to multiple-servers

Tags: nginx, websocket

I know `Nginx` can balance traffic with some strategy for example `round robin` and `hash` and so on.

Since `HTTP` is `stateless`, they can be switched to multiple servers without any problem.

I want Nginx to work with `Websocket` the same as `HTTP`.

But being different from `HTTP`, `Websocket` has to retain the connection to a specific server after `hand-shaking` with the server.

I think it means that `Nginx` can balance this `hand-shaking` procedure but after this procedure the traffic only goes to into the server where the client had the connection first but the others.

Any suggestion?